# how to set the Cordova configuration?

Tags: javascript, cordova, url-routing

When I build applications by Cordova, for example for browser: "cordova run browser" I get a blank page "Not found", and the path in the address bar as follows:

> localhost:8000/index.html

But if I remove from the address bar index.html and address bar is a 
`localhost:8000/` everything works perfect.
I tried in the config cordova to change the string for the src attribute - i write null string. Then everything from the start worked perfectly. 
But when I run the build for Android by cordova  -this case no longer works and I get the error "`Page not found`". What is the solve of this problem for that case?

I already have `index.html`:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,     maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
  <meta name="description" content="Use Ionic with React"/>
  <title>Reactionic React Ionic</title></head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/fonts.css">
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

But I want my app run on my phone with the address bar: `localhost:8000`/ without `index.html`

Comment: Do you have a src value in `<content/>` in config.xml?

Comment: Yes: <content src="index.html" />
But if I write <content src="" /> - I get error: "Page not found"

Comment: That's telling cordova what your start page is.  Leave it as index.html and create an index.html.  That's what it expects you to do.

Comment: I already have index.html